# Thermostat independently controlling and registering heat use for multiple zones with remote on/off?

Tags: smart-device, power-control

I am looking for a smart-ish thermostat, which can:

- Separate usage for, say, heating zone 1, heating zone 2 and hot water. Heating zone 2 might be radiators heated by a gas boiler or an air to air heat pump. If it could show usage as the time where the thermostat is asking the controlled units to heat, then that would be OK on that point.
- I should also be able to switch either zone on/off remotely from different devices (this is more important to me than any "learning" ability).
- Ideally it would be able to control solar thermal hot water should I go completely green and add it later.

(Hopefully this counts as in-scope as it would be a device connected to via a computer/smartphone. Thank you!)

Comment: What's your budget?

Comment: Ideally less than £200, but if that was without solar thermal support, I could think about that later, it is not given I'd go ahead with it.